# Convert Spreadsheet to Data Frame Syntax in Python

Tags: python, excel, pandas

Out of the box (and broad) question here: I have a spreadsheet that I'd like to use as an example in a question to the SO community, but I have a feeling most SO helpers would not like to deal with spreadsheets as data input/examples.

Instead, I'd like to provide an already-transformed data frame for you; however, I am not sure how to do this.

I'd like to generate code that will take spreadsheet columns and turn them into a single data frame syntax code that I can easily share here.

Example of how the data frame syntax would be:

```
# Example of data frame 'syntax code'

import pandas as pd
df = {'A' : ['B','C','D'], '1': [2,3,4]}
df = pd.DataFrame(df)
```

etc...

In essence, every column of the spreadsheet would be it's own respective column in the said pandas data frame.  Any blanks would correspond to `np.nan`.

The overall idea here is to import two spreadsheets as data frames and make comparisons between them for differences.

Simply put, how can I turn spreadsheet values into something like `{'A' : ['B','C','D'], '1': [2,3,4]}` with code?

Comment: How about `pd.read_excel('path/to/file.xlsx').head(5).to_dict()` to read an excel file, get the first 5 rows, and convert it to a dict format that anyone can easily pass to `pd.DataFrame`?

Comment: Asking about the proper way to present input data shows that you are on the path to wisdom... And as you have been told, loading a spreadsheet into a dataframe is just a `read_xxx` function, and then `to_dict` is enough to convert a dataframe into a dict for helping answerers .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nice question, and thank you for caring about the community in this way! You're right that it makes it a lot easier to help with problems with we have to do as little work *to get set up* as possible. :)

Unless your spreadsheet has complex formatting/coloring, or complex columns or that sort of stuff, it should be as simple to convert your spreadsheet to a portable datastructure for `pd.DataFrame` as

```
pd.read_excel('path/to/file.xlsx').head(5).to_dict()
```

Note the `.head(5)` - that selects only the first 5 rows, because if your spreadsheet is large, having many rows will likely make everything harder if you don't *need* to give us those extra rows.